# How to get hyper link ID by using div class?

Tags: jquery

This is my code below:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

   $("#video1").fancybox({'width': '30%',
            'height'            : '20em',
            'autoScale'         : false,
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'type'              : 'iframe'});
```

} );

```
   <div class="fancybox"><a id="video1 href="#">Video1</a></div>
   <div class="fancybox"><a id="video2 href="#">Video2</a></div>
```

So if there are 7 fancybox classes in div, I need to write 7 duplicated functions. Is there any way that I can use

```
    $('.fancybox').('a')
```

or something like that to use only one function to control them all. 
Fancybox is a light box of video or img, basically if you click one of the link, a video will pop up.

Comment: $('.fancybox').find('a') is your friend

Comment: unrelative to your question - you are forgetting to end your `id="` quote in `<a id="video1 href=` should be `<a id="video1" href="`

Comment: Thank you for help, I tried to use $('.fancybox a').fancybox(), but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do

```
$('.fancybox a')
```

It should cover all instances

Here is a fiddle of it at work

http://jsfiddle.net/N4EwH/

```
$('.fancybox a').click(function(){alert('clicked');});
```

Make sure you fix the syntax errors in your html.  That might cause the issue.  See my fiddle for the changes. (you missed the closing quotation marks)

Comment: Is any of this being built dynamically?  This really should work.  Please see my updated answer.

Comment: No, just a simple video link in each of them. I used $('.fancybox a').fancybox()

Comment: hah, it works now! I missed a typo. Thanks! I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$('.fancybox a').fancybox({
   // your set up code
});
```

Note you're also missing a closing double quote on the `id` parameters of the `a` elements.